# Identify stores with same location in Bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

So, let's say I have this data:

```
store_name               | latitude    | longitude | store_id | same_location_count | same_location_store_id
SR Restaurant and Cafe   | -41.575449  | 147.16824 | 1112     | 0           | null
Big Bite Burgers         | -41.575449  | 147.16824 | 1113     | 0           | null
Amigos                   | -41.575449  | 147.16824 | 1114     | 0           | null
Domino's                 | -38.33983   | 143.58384 | 1115     | 0           | null
```

I want to identity the stores that are in same coordinates.

The expected result looks like this:

```
store_name               | latitude    | longitude | store_id | same_location_count | same_location_store_id
SR Restaurant and Cafe   | -41.575449  | 147.16824 | 1112     | 2           | 1113:1114
Big Bite Burgers         | -41.575449  | 147.16824 | 1113     | 2           | 1112:1114
Amigos                   | -41.575449  | 147.16824 | 1114     | 2           | 1112:1113
Domino's                 | -38.33983   | 143.58384 | 1115     | 0           | null
```

If the stores are in same coordinates, we increment the `same_location_count` and get the ID of the same store location and concatenate it to `same_location_store_id`.

Comment: what the data type of following columns: `latitude`, `longitude`, `store_id` - usually those are `FLOAT64`, `FLOAT64`, `INT64` - please clarify!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use count and string_agg function for achieving this.

Test code:

```
with test as (
  select 'id1' id, '-41.575449' lat, '1112' long
  union all
  select 'id2' id, '-41.575449' lat, '1112' long
  union all
  select 'id3' id, '-41.575449' lat, '1112' long
  union all
  select 'id4' id, '-38.33983' lat, '1115' long
)
SELECT
  *,
  (COUNT(id) OVER (PARTITION BY lat, long))-1 AS same_location_count,
  REPLACE( STRING_AGG(CONCAT(id,':'),'') OVER (PARTITION BY lat, long), CONCAT(id,':'), '') AS same_location_store_id
FROM
  test
```

Edit: match the exact scenario without counting the id of each row and excluding it from the concatenation.

Comment: Almost, but each store with same coordinates shouldn't included itself in the incrementation and concatenation of store Ids. :)

Comment: This is a very beautiful answer @Gumaz. I just subtract the `same_location_count` by 1 and replace the each store id from `same_location_store_id` to "". Can you please edit the answer so it will match the answer of my question so I can tag it as correct answer? For the future explorer also...

Comment: I just added a little bit of string processing for achieving exact values for same_location_store_id field and delimiters

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something similar to the following.
This works for Postgres DB, I think it should work in BigQuery also?

```sql
SELECT
  stores.*,
  COUNT(store_id) OVER (PARTITION BY latitude,longitude) - 1 AS same_location_count,
  NULLIF(
    TRIM(REPLACE(
      CONCAT(':', STRING_AGG(CAST(store_id AS TEXT), ':') OVER (PARTITION BY latitude,longitude), ':'),
      CONCAT(':', CAST(store_id AS TEXT), ':'),
      ':'
    ), ':'),
    ''
  ) AS same_location_store_id
FROM stores
```

Fiddle link: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gUfJm7X75Fdx1nuy9hSrsD/1

**Edit**: Updated from comment.

Count is the easy part; just subtract 1 from value.
Same location stores you can see has become a horrible mess...

Basically the logic is:

1. Collect all store_ids for same location (now using string_agg instead of array_agg
2. Make a string of `:idA:idB:...:idN:` with leading,trailing :
3. Remove the store_id of same store by replace ":id:" with just ":"
4. Tidy up afterwards to make sure null for empty string, and remove leading,trailing : again

Step 3 works only because store_id is integer, and so guaranteed not to contain separator char :

Comment: Almost, but each store with same coordinates shouldn't included itself in the incrementation and concatenation of store Ids. :)

Comment: Updated @ArciM. Not so elegant but I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Consider below approach (BigQuery)

```
select * except(x), 
  (( select as struct count(*) as same_location_count,
      string_agg('' || id, ':' order by id) as same_location_store_id
    from t.x id
    where id != store_id
  )).*
from (
  select *, array_agg(store_id) over (partition by '' || latitude, '' || longitude) as x, 
  from your_table
) t
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Note: I am assuming the data type of `latitude`, `longitude`, `store_id` columns are respectively `FLOAT64`, `FLOAT64`, `INT64` and that is why you see in few places something like `'' || latitude` - this is to cast them to STRING. So if those columns already STRINGs  - you can remove  `'' ||`  part

Comment: What if there is another column called same_location_store_name, what will be the sql select statement for that?

Comment: you should post the new question with all related details so we will be happy to help then